# Кнопка добавить корзину для вариативных товаров в категории WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вывести в категории кнопку добавления в корзину
(вместо - выбрать опции) для вариативных товаров.

Например, есть у товара 4 размера - XS,S,M,L. Размер XS указан по умолчанию. Нужно в рубрике сразу добавлять его в корзину.

Спасибо

---

Размер у меня указан по умолчанию так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На странице товара все ок, а вот как заменить теперь кнопку - "выбрать опции" на "добить в корзину" в категории, не понятно(

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо выбрать размер и цвет (если он участвует в вариациях) по умолчанию в товаре в списке вариаций. В таком случае будет автоматом доступна возможность положить вариацию, что задана по умолчанию.
На картинке у меня называется поле "значение форм по умолчанию" .
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видите, размер не выбран и требует выбора от покупателя, а если его задать, то он будет по умолчанию...
**НО** на мой взгляд, это не правильно, Вы не должны выбирать за клиента и навязывать размер по умолчанию. Утверждаю по личном опыту, **будет много ошибок в заказах**, люди не смотрят, а сначала тыкают купить, а потом пишут и звонят или бросают заказ, не разобравшись как удалить или заменить размер.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Повторюсь, размер у меня указан по умолчанию так, как вы описали 

На странице товара все ок, а вот как заменить теперь кнопку - выбрать опцию в рубрике?

Comment: Я протестировал у себя в магазине, если выбраны умолчания то кнопка выбрать, меняется на купить. В настройке **WooCommerce** установлено в настройки/товар/основные/ группа страницы магазина - "Включить Ajax для кнопки добавления в корзину из архивов"